# Create a Deque using only arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, deque

I have been tasked with creating an deque using only arrays in c++ and am getting a little hung up when it comes to popping off the front or back(deleting the element at the head or tail of the deque. I much prefer Java and am not very comfortable with c++ so I do not know if this is a problem of me not knowing the language well enough or my logic being incorrect. Here is my code by the way. The method pop front is the issue right now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

//#include "DeQue.h"
using namespace std;

class Deque{
private:
    std::string *queue;             //The array which holds the queue
    std::string deque[];
    int numElements;                //The number of elements in the queue
    int sizeOfQueue;                //The capacity of the queue
    int front;                      //Points to the front of the queue
    int back;                       //Points to the back of the queue

public:
    //Constructor
    Deque() {
        string deque[8] = {"a","b","c"};
        this->numElements = 3;
        this->sizeOfQueue = 8;
        this->front = 0;
        this->back = 2;

    }

    //Destructor
    ~Deque() {

    }

    //Inserts the element at the front of the queue.
    void push_front(std::string item){
        if(front==0){
            deque[sizeOfQueue-1] = item;
            front = sizeOfQueue-1;
        }
        else if(front >= 1 && front < sizeOfQueue - 1)
            deque[front-1] = item;
            front--;
    }

    //Inserts the element at the back of the queue
    void push_back(std::string item) {
        if(back==sizeOfQueue-1){
            deque[0] = item;
            back = 0;
        }
        else if(back < sizeOfQueue-1 && back >= 0){
            deque[back+1] = item;
            back++;
        }
    }

    //Deletes the element at the front of the queue
    std::string pop_front() {
        delete deque[front];
        if(front == sizeOfQueue-1)
            front = 0;
        else
            front++;
    }
```

I am new to stackoverflow as far as posting questions so please let me know if I can format this question any better. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For the problematic part, please describe exactly what you see happening and what you expected to happen.

Comment: Look up circular-buffer.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It will not even compile at this point. I don't know how to remove an array element without creating a new array with one less. I am expecting the element at the "front" of the deque to be removed. I also cannot simply set the element to null because it is "not declared in this scope"

Comment: You don't literally have to _remove_ an element from the array, instead adjust your `front` and/or `back` pointers as needed to exclude the element you are popping from the currently active part of the array.

Comment: `string deque[8]` in the constructor hides the member of the same name and does not work like you might think.

Comment: @crashmstr: Well spotted.

Comment: @crashmstr what do you mean?

Comment: @KevinMarin `string deque[8] = {"a","b","c"};` creates a *new* local variable that *hides* the `deque` member variable. Assignment to the local variable does not affect the member variable.

Comment: So should i use "this->" to fix that? When i tried that before it gave me an error.

Comment: @KevinMarin If this is a homework assignment, be aware that this: `std::string deque[];` is not valid C++, but is a non-standard extension.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes it is a homework assignment, but in the description he gave us    std::string *queue; and I did not know what to do with it

Comment: @crashmstr I forgot to tag you in my above comment

Comment: @KevinMarin - `std::string deque[8];` this is what the member variable should be, not a local variable as your code was doing.  Then in the constructor, assign each element to the array.  That is the easiest thing to do, even if it is more typing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks that fixed a couple of the funcionality problems I was having earlier. I still do not know how to remove an element from the array when I want to pop back or pop front. Is there a way to set that element to null?

Comment: @KevinMarin the reason it won't work is that you can't *assign* like that, only *initialize*. You also need to specify a size of the array or use `new []` to allocate space.

Comment: Right, I took you guys advice and it fixed some of my problems. However I still have the problem issue with "popping". Is there a way to remove an array element without copying the array sans element to be removed? Because that will make my runtime very slow.

Comment: @crashmstr I keep forgetting to tag in a comment sorry

Comment: @KevinMarin with an array based stack or queue, you can just move the `front` and `back`, so you don't need to actually *remove* the value from the array, you just make it so that is it not within that valid range of `front` to `back`.

Comment: @crashmstr Unfortunately for the assignment we also have to design the deque so that when it gets full the size doubles and when it gets down to 1/4 full the size reduces by half, so wont all those hanging values that are outside the range of 'front' and 'back' complicate things when that happens?

Comment: @KevinMarin no, since you only worry about values from `front` to `back` it does not matter even if you copy them. *As a note:* if you need to resize, you need to allocate with `new[]` and free with `delete[]` with a `std::string *`.

Comment: @crashmstr So I should convert my array to a pointer array?

Comment: @KevinMarin you can't resize an array. You can only get a `new[]` one of a different size and copy the data. To do that, you need a pointer *to* an array (`std::string *ar = new std::string[5]` vs. `std::string ar[5]`)

Comment: @crashmstr Oh okay okay. I think I got it now. Thank you for your help!